# Would a Google+ public posting be considered an invention disclosure?

Tags: google, facebook, invention, plus

If I post my idea, in detail, even with drawings, on a public Google+ post, would that be considered to be an accurately dated disclosure?

It seems it would establish the dates of invention, both publicly, and verifiably from Googles own servers, and the internet archive.

Same concept would go for a Facebook public posting.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might depend on how public that posting was. Both of those social networks have privacy settings which limit the exposure to your posts. Was it posted to a single individual? Probably not considered disclosure. Public to the world, probably considered disclosure.

However, any such could establish a date for invention.

Comment: Establishing a date of conception is not as valuable as it was under the old first-to-invent law. Now the U.S. is a first-to-file country, like most of the rest of the world.

Comment: It would form part of the prior art base unless all who had access to the material were explicitly told it was confidential. There is a lot of case law where information has been deemed public under far more private / confidential circumstances than a social network.

Comment: You should also add that if the posting of the information to only a select few people, there also has to be an agreement that the information will not be shared with other people. If not, that disclosure of more than 12 months can lead to a bar.